# Upgrading Ionic 5 [Angular] project to Ionic 6, having issues with dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to update my Ionic 5 project to Ionic 6. I followed the steps outlined on the ionic page stating the command to upgrade is:

```
npm install @ionic/angular@6
```

The output I am getting is this, I don't know how to solve this problem:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: Project@0.0.2
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@8.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~8.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@">=12.0.0" from @ionic/angular@6.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!   @ionic/angular@"6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /x/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /x/.npm/_logs/2022-10-11T23_20_13_132Z-debug.log
```

Instructions I followed from are here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/upgrading-to-ionic-6

Answer (score 1):

Read your error:

```
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@8.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~8.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@">=12.0.0" from @ionic/angular@6.3.0
```

Even though you have not posted your package.json it is safe bet you have Angular 8.1.2 installed and NOT the minimum of Angular 12+ as stated in the first bullet point of the upgrade guide you linked.

"Ionic 6 supports Angular 12+. Update to the latest version of Angular by following the Angular Update Guide."